# Passing an empty array to sum() and product()

Tags: python, arrays, fortran

In the following code, I'm passing an empty array to intrinsic `sum()` and `product()` functions.

```
program test
    implicit none
    integer, allocatable :: A(:)

    allocate( A( 0 ) )

    print *, "sum     = ", sum( A )
    print *, "product = ", product( A )
end
```

Then, all the compilers I've tried give the same result:

```
 sum     =  0
 product =  1
```

So I'm wondering (1) whether it is allowed to pass an empty array to those functions, and (2) if so, the results are guaranteed to be 0 and 1 (by the Fortran standards). For comparison, some other languages (e.g. Python3) also give 0 and 1, which (I guess) may be related to the limit of `sum( [1,2,...,n] )` and `product( [1,2,...,n] )` to `n -> 0`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.sum( [] )
0.0
>>> np.prod( [] )
1.0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is allowed to pass zero-sized arrays to those intrinsics (and many others) and yes those results are explicitly required by the Fortran standard.

For `product` (F2008, 13.7.133):

> The result of PRODUCT (ARRAY) has a value equal to a processor-dependent approximation to the product of all the elements of ARRAY or has the value one if ARRAY has size zero.

For `sum` (F2008, 13.7.161):

> The result of SUM (ARRAY) has a value equal to a processor-dependent approximation to the sum of all the elements of ARRAY or has the value zero if ARRAY has size zero.

Comment: These intrinsic s

Answer (score 0):

These intrinsics have the same specified behavior since f90, and those compilers which had it wrong were corrected once bug reports were processed. You may be thinking of related intrinsics like maxloc which were first defined for 0 size in f2003 and still certain compilers have options to violate the standard in favor of optimization with correct behavior at nonzero size.